# Can one convert a variable string to D3 data reference?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**UPDATE:**

I initially agreed that the answer provided in the "duplicate" question helped, but it didn't. This isn't a duplicate question because I am trying to convert the string into a column name to use with d as in using dynamic and multiple data. The answer provided **still uses a string** and references data statically as in Data[0]["myString"] but what I am looking for is d.MyColumnWhichUsedToBeAString

**ORIGINAL:**

I would like to take a string from an array and then use that value to find the corresponding csv data.

Is this possible? If so, how:

Example:

```
//Ultimately, I want to return d.one

var myArray = ["one", "two", "three"}

//Is there a a way to get d.one from the array. For example

d.myArray[0]
```

Comment: @jtbandes Can this question be un-marked as a duplicate? It is not a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript you need to use the `[]` property accessor syntax for variable index names:

```
var theValue = d[myArray[0]]
```